# Eclipse IDE : could not find or load main class

Tags: eclipse

I am getting this error for every single program I create and run.
Is there any permanent solution for this error.
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Exactly how are you creating and running them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, you seem to have a problem with your librairies(JAR) :

1. Right click on your **Project > Properties > JavaBuildPath > Libraries**.
2. Remove the jar file, having a red flag on it.
3. If problem persists try the solution below. This worked for me when I faced this problem second time:

   1. *Right-Click* **Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries**
   2. Remove Library
   3. Add Library. (Choose the JRE System Library )

Comment: Yes, This works but I have to do it for every project i create. Is there any solution for this??

Comment: Then try one of this : 
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs hit the default JRE (the checked one) and Edit. Or Window - Preferences - Java - Build Path - User Libraries